Why do they have to fake the protagonist's death?
The last episode of Healer left me confused.
They have the evidence of the bad guys doing bad things with bioweapons.
They caught them red-handed trying to kill the whistleblower.
The police are already on board, so know what is happening and don't think the protagonist is a suspect anymore.
If they send him to a tropical island to leave in the anonymity, I will have understood, but then he just ended doing cameraman work.
So, why do they have to fake the police shooting Healer?

We have seen this kind of stuff in many movies where a person who may have some evidence to support to police in an investigation of a crime got threatened by the powerful individuals or groups involved in that crime. And to save them fake deaths got planned.
So in the current drama context:
By faking his death in a police shootout, they try to make sure that the protagonist can effectively disappear from the radar of these potential threats. It allows him to start a new life away from the dangers that have troubled him.
Additionally, the decision for the protagonist to work as a cameraman could be seen as a way for him to remain active while maintaining a low profile. It's a way for him to use his skills without drawing attention to himself.
Below are the two close movie plots coming into my mind:
The Departed: Although the police not faking the protagonist's death, there's a similar plot element where the police manipulate information about the protagonist's death to protect him from the criminals.
Die Hard with a Vengeance: In this film, the protagonist, John McClane, portrayed by Bruce Willis, is manipulated by the police into faking his death to get the plan details of a terrorist named Simon Gruber.
